# How to partially overwrite __repr__ for a class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, repr

I'm learning Python and it's my first question here :)

So I am defining a class:

```
class Nr_Heap:
    def __init__(self):
        self._top = None          #a queue() of Point()
        self._tmp_bottom = None   #a Point()

    def __str__(self):
        if self._top != None:
            if self.top:
                return f"Nr Heap of [{', '.join([f'{str(self.top[i])}' for i in range(len(self.top))])}]"
            else:
                return f"Nr Heap of [...empty...]"
        else:
            return f"Nr Heap (not used)"
```

The `__str__` method seems to be doing what I want it to do, but I'm wandering, is it possible to write a `__repr__` method, so that it would partially overwrite the default `__repr__`, that is only in case, when my `__str__` is returning `f"Nr Heap [{', '.join([f'{str(self.top[i])}' for i in range(len(self.top))])}]"`?

Let me show it on example. When I initiate the Nr_Heap() object, the output is:

```
str(nh):  Nr Heap (not used)
repr(nh):  <conflicts.Nr_Heap object at 0x7f2e02d1bfd0>
```

Then I set Nr_Heap .top to be an empty collections.deque() and I get:

```
str(nh):  Nr Heap of [...empty...]
repr(nh):  <conflicts.Nr_Heap object at 0x7f2e02d1bfd0>
```

And lastly, after adding 3 points to the queue:

```
str(nh):  Nr Heap of [Point: 3(3, 3), Point: 2(2, 2), Point: 1(1, 1)]
repr(nh):  <conflicts.Nr_Heap object at 0x7f2e02d1bfd0>
```

and only in the last case I want a `__repr__` method to return something like this:

```
<conflicts.Nr_Heap object: [Point: 3(3, 3), Point: 2(2, 2), Point: 1(1, 1)]>
```

How to do that?

Comment: well, implement `__repr__` and check whether `self.top` is truthy? I don't really understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like the following should be possible:

```
def __repr__(self):
    if str(self) == "some fixed string"
        return super().__repr__()
    return "some other repr string"
```

or whatever you're preferred if-condition is (`if self.top` may be another option).

The key is to use `super().__repr__()` to return the default repr result. That default will take into account the current class, so it behaves as if you hadn't implemented `__repr__` at all.